# Browser (SPNEGO) kerberos authentication on Windows Phone 8 IE

Tags: kerberos, internet-explorer, single-sign-on, mobile-devices, windows-phone-7

Is there a way to make Internet Explorer on Windows Phone 8 authenticate to a site using Windows Integrated Security Authentication with Kerberos through the Negotiate (SPNEGO) protocol?

It seems to support Negotiate fine, but it only ever chooses NTLM. (confirming using techniques from [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/423161/how-can-i-check-if-my-iis-site-is-using-ntlm-or-kerberos))

On desktop browsers you typically have to opt-in to site to allow this type of authentication either through a whitelist of URLs (firefox, iOS7+ Safari, newer versions of Chrome) or through detection of an Intranet site (OSX Safari or non-phone IE).

Comment: Should be tagged as windows-phone-8, but I don't have the rep here,  can someone create that tag and replace windows-phone-7 tag on this question?

Comment: Kerberos only works with domain machines - see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14224580/iis-using-kerberos-with-client-computers-that-are-not-on-the-domain

Comment: @Christopher_G_Lewis iOS7 iPhones/iPads can do it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18813517/single-sign-on-sso-in-ios-7. While the configuration of this can be done w/ a centralized MDM server, it's not like they join the domain. I made this work on my companies domain simply by emailing a .mobileconfig file to my iPhone.  Example: http://samuelyates.wordpress.com/2013/10/11/kerberos-single-sign-on-in-ios-7/    My point being if Apple can do it, why not MS?

Comment: Samsung phones w/ Knox 2.0 reportedly can do this too. See https://www.samsungknox.com/en/blog/improved-single-sign-sso-samsung-knox I have a support ticket open w/ them since I can't make this work . (I may need to get a newer samsung device, support for Knox features varies greatly by device - I guess having 4 Samsung phones/tablets is not enough :eyeroll:)

Comment: Aardvark - seems like it might actually work - https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CDcQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.microsoft.com%2Fdownload%2FF%2F7%2F9%2FF79CA111-D960-4F7D-9F11-978D0B3E2895%2FS11%2520Network%2520Communication.pdf&ei=CxhUUdpByM6tB7y8gXg&usg=AFQjCNHSKLxx3l7SHaHZR2DwNp8iz2DJWw&bvm=bv.44342787,d.bmk but I haven't seen any further proof.